# Dynamically loop on keys of object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an object coming from upload

```
obj: {
    name: 'Mike'
    street: 'Love'
}
```

and I can loop through it via

```
<div v-for="test in obj">
    <span>{{test.name}}, {{test.street}}</span>
</div>
```

and I get fine output.

However, the object keys became different depending on user upload, sometimes the key will become

```
obj: {
    address: 'street test 123',
    fine: '32 PHP',
    magic: 'Love'
}
```

How can I loop through it to become dynamic?

Comment: Based on your sample code, you are already doing it dynamically by iterating over the _value_ of the object. In which case `{{test.name}}` and `{{test.street}}` shouldn't even work as expected, since conceptually you're doing `<div><span  v-for="value in obj">{{ value }}</span></div>`. But of course there's more than this, such as touching on adding comma at the end of each part except the last one.

Comment: i can output it via {{test.name}} {{test.street}} however the keys will became different at some other time so i cant use anymore the  {{test.name}} {{test.street}} i need it to become dynamic

Comment: Why it works for you, maybe you're giving an incomplete picture. But you really just need to follow https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object, and you would be able to handle dynamic keys of uploaded object.

Comment: I think obj is an array these `obj`s ? Is that right ? Because, as @woozyking mentioned you are already using the v-for for objects.

Answer (score 0):

you have to take all keys in one array then you can bind it.

```
obj: {
address: 'street test 123',
fine: '32 PHP',
magic: 'Love'
}

var keys = Object.keys(obj);


<div>
    <span>{{keys.join(,)}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through the whole object like this, here `index` is the variable name and `item` is the value

```js
var app4 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-4',
  data: {
    obj: {
      address: 'street test 123',
      fine: '32 PHP',
      magic: 'Love'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app-4">
<div v-for="(item, index) in obj">
    <span>{{item}}</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to use `v-for` for this purpose.

This is what I would do without changing how you have your `obj` set up:

```
<div id="foo">
  {{computedVal}}
</div>
```

and in the `Vue` instance,

```
new Vue({
   data: {
     // ... miscellaneous stuff
     obj: {
       prop1: 'val1',
       prop2: 'val2',
       prop3: 'val3',
     }
   },
   methods:{ /* ... */ },
   computed: {
      computedVal(){
        let str = '';
        for(let key in this.obj){
          let val = this.obj[key];
          str += `<span>${key} : ${val}</span>`;
        }
        return str;
      }
   }
});
```

This will be your output:

```
<div id="foo">
   <span>prop1 : val1</span>
   <span>prop2 : val2</span>
   <span>prop3 : val3</span>
</div>
```

Of course you can do this inside `v-for` as well.

My understanding is that as of now, Vue doesn't do object property iteration inside `v-for`.